# Is a log transformation valid for a pre-experiment sample size calculation using 2-sided z test?

Tags: sample-size, z-test

**Goal**

I am conducting a pre-experiment analysis to determine what the necessary sample size is given a specific power, significance level, and lift.

**Data**

This is for a research question where I have a distribution of monetary deposits from a large sample (large enough to be considered the population it is drawn from).

**Method**

I have tried to reproduce a standard sample size calculation I found in several references including this [link](https://www.biostat.wisc.edu/%7Elindstro/13.sample.size.10.20.pdf). This is an image from slide 12 with the formula. Power = $\beta$, significance level = $\alpha$ and the lift is given by $\mu_1-\mu_2$.

[image: sample size calc]

From my understanding, this approach assumes the data is normally distributed and the eventual experiment would use a 2-sided Z test. Additionally, since it is pre-experiment data, $\sigma_1^2$ is set equal to $\sigma_2^2$ (no treatment has been applied as of yet).

However, the distribution of the deposits data is lognormal. So, I applied a base 10 log transformation to make it more normal. This means the input lift is now a relative ratio rather than an absolute difference in means, but I don't think that changes the overall validity of this calculation: log($\mu_1$) - log($\mu_2$) = log($\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}$).

**I want to know if it is valid to use a log transformation on dollar values for a pre-experiment sample size calculation.** Other suggested approaches that I was given include using the Mann Whitney U test, but I am not sure how to do a pre-experiment sample size calculation for that one. I found this [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3113/parametric-sample-size-calculation-and-non-parametric-analysis?rq=1) but none of the reference links are still active.

Thanks for the help.